# OAuth 2 Authlib. How to access resource?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I have set up [this](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) example OAuth2 server. It has authorization and one resource (`/api/me`). I am making a client app also in python. I figured out how to get token. But when I try to access `/api/me` I get response `{"message":"401 Unauthorized: None"}`. I can say that I put my token in URL as a param, AND also I put it in FORM. It put it under `access_token` key. What am I doing wrong? Obviously it should work somehow?

Here is my client app code:

```
    def token_get():
    token = None
    print("========================================")
    print("Sending POST request to get token")
    # FORM data
    payload = {
        "client_id":"ySFTzBKLo0XTaK2tQL9ls4Fc",
        "client_secret":"vq8vMZplY4J00FrxKx4ynV2mhmL2zzjMzP1U2bXZPhQRcmJl",
        "grant_type":"password", 
        "scope":"profile",
        "username":"ignas",
        "password":"valid"
    }
    auth=(
        "ySFTzBKLo0XTaK2tQL9ls4Fc",
        "vq8vMZplY4J00FrxKx4ynV2mhmL2zzjMzP1U2bXZPhQRcmJl"
    )
    r = requests.post(_url(f"/oauth/token"), data=payload, auth=auth)
    print(f"RESPONSE {r.status_code}")
    print(f"r.url={r.url}")
    print(f"r.text={r.text}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        json = r.json()
        print(f"JSON=\"{json}\"")
        token = json["access_token"]
        print(f"TOKEN=\"{token}\"")
    print("========================================")

    return token

def api_me_get(token):
    print("========================================")
    print("Sending GET request to get protected data of me")
    # FORM data
    payload = {
        "access_token":f"{token}"
    }
    print(f"PAYLOAD=\"{payload}\"")
    r = requests.get(_url(f"/api/me"), data=payload, params=payload)
    print(f"RESPONSE {r.status_code}")
    print(f"r.url={r.url}")
    print(f"r.text={r.text}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        json = r.json()
        print(f"JSON=\"{json}\"")
    print("========================================")

def test_token():
    token = token_get()
    api_me_get(token)

def main():
    test_token()

main()
```